# what is wrong with my sql statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am doing a project in VBA. I have succesfully connected and retrieved my tables. Now I want to update several columns from Excel. When I run this code it doesn't throw any errors but the values in my table never change.

```
sqlstr = "UPDATE " & table4 & " SET price = '" & Cells(i, 8) & ", & " 
& Cells(i, 9) & "' " & " WHERE key_id = '" & Cells(i, 1) & ", & " & Cells(i, 2) & "' "
```

When I run a shorter version with one value then it updates it alright.

```
sqlstr = "UPDATE " & table4 & " SET price = '" & Cells(i, 8) & "' " & " 
WHERE key_id = '" & Cells(i, 1) & "' "
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? You have an '&' inside  a quote which is probably breaking stuff. What is cells(I,9) doing? Usually Update Statements are like: Update Table set Column = Value, Column2 = Value2 where Clause

Comment: It's also a SQL injection risk.

Comment: Those are not SQL statements.  Those are VBA statements that build an SQL statement.  The resulting SQL statement is in the variable `sqlstr`.  If you display the contents of that variable, you will probably immediately see the syntax error in the constructed SQL statement.

Comment: As I said it is updating the table from Excel using Vba Macros. The second example updates it alright, that is it updates one value. I want to update several values at once using that script

Comment: @LarryLustig how do I display the contents of that variable?

Comment: I'm not 100% what you were trying to do with the query (You want to update the price to be the value of 2 cells?  And the where clause specifies two values too?)  But this should (i think) update your field to be cells i8 and i9 concatanated together with a comma in the middle, where they key id equal to cell i1 or i2  ---   Sql = sqlstr = "UPDATE " & table4 & " SET price = ('" & Cells(i, 8) & "' & ',' & '" & Cells(i, 9) & "') WHERE key_id = '" & Cells(i, 1) & "' OR key_id = '" & Cells(i, 2) & "' "

Comment: I want something like this: UPDATE product_discount SET price = 10, 15 WHERE key_id = 1 , 2. I want to update multiple rows at once with one query.

Answer (score 0):

you  missing ' quotes in your syntax

```
sqlstr = "UPDATE " & table4 & " SET price = '" & Cells(i, 8) & "' " & " 
& Cells(i, 9) & "' " & " WHERE key_id = '" & Cells(i, 1) & ", & " & Cells(i, 2) & "' "
```

Comment: But guys, do is this statemnet right? UPDATE product_discount SET price = '10,15' WHERE key_id = '1,2'